# mysql select query for multiple ID's that call name from same username table

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Quick question. feel like a noob but haven't found the right syntax for this yet.

Have 3 tables.

T1-
AsessessmentID(auto Incr)
inspectorID,
assistantID,
plant name

T2-
UserID(auto Incr),
username,
name

T3-
plantID(auto Incr)
PlantName

Basically I want to have a php/mysql table that is very similar to T1 but instead of listing the ID's I would like the names. Heres my call so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.AssessmentID, u.Name, a.PlantAssistID, p.PlantName 
                FROM assessmentscores AS a, user AS u, plant AS p
                WHERE u.userID=a.InspectorID AND u.Name='$name' AND p.PlantID=a.Plant
```

This works as u.Name will give me the name for the inspector but I can't figure out how to call the second (a.PlantAssistID). Just keep getting the same name for both.

What call to the server should I use to return two different names. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This question is slightly vague; providing us with a example of an expected result would likely be a great improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: if you want to select from the assessment table and augment the resultset using the other tables, think about using `LEFT JOIN`. If you want a more restrictive result, where only assessments are returned that are actually associated with existing users, use an `INNER JOIN` instead. The example below uses `LEFT JOIN`.

Not sure whether this is what you want exactly, but you can try:

```
SELECT a.AssessmentID as a_id, u.Name as u_name, a.PlantAssistID as a_plantassistid, p.PlantName as p_plantname, uass.Name as u_ass_name
    FROM assessmentscores a
    LEFT JOIN user u ON u.UserID = a.AssessmentID
    LEFT JOIN plant p ON p.PlantID = a.Plant
    LEFT JOIN user uass ON uass.UserID = a.PlantAssistentID
```

Result:

```
array(
    'a_id'            => int    /* AssessmentID */
    'u_name'          => string /* User name */
    'a_plantassistid' => int    /* Assessment.PlantAssistID */
    'p_plantname'     => string /* Plant name */
    'u_ass_name'      => string /* The user name of the user with assistent_id */
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure I follow you, but here's what I think you want:

I would rewrite the query to use JOIN, as the can be easier to read

```
SELECT a.AssessmentID, u.Name, a.PlantAssistID, p.PlantName, u2.Name as AssisantName
FROM user AS u
    JOIN assessmentscores AS a ON u.UserID = a.InspectorID
    JOIN plant AS p ON p.plantID = a.Plant
    JOIN user as u2 ON u2.UserID = a.assistantId
WHERE u.Name='$name'
```

The key here is to rejoin on the user table but to give it a different alias (u2 here)

Comment: awesome, just what i needed. thanks to you and pelle ten cate